# tcl proc using upvar resulting in history(nextid)

Tags: tcl, procedure, upvar

I'm getting this weird issue. 
i'm using tcl 8.3

after i define this proc in a tcl shell

```
% proc incr { varName {amount 1}} {
    puts $varName
    upvar #0 $varName var
    puts $varName
    if {[info exists var]} {
       set var [expr $var + $amount]
    } else {
       set var $amount
    }
    return $var
}
```

i keep getting

```
%
history(nextid)
history(nextid)
history(oldest)
history(oldest)
%
```

Everytime i hit newline "Enter" after that
any one has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You might just want to `upvar $varName var` -- using `#0` means you can only use your proc with global variables, local variables won't be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the history managment is written in Tcl itself, and that uses `incr`.

Your `incr` is almost equal to Tcl 8.3's `incr` with some differences:

- The name of the variable is always printed
- If the variable does not exist, it will be created.

So if you remove the first difference (the `puts`) everything will work as expected, just that some library commands may call your `incr` instead the standard `incr`.

The second difference is now in the core, IIRC starting with Tcl 8.5 it is not nessencary that a variable already exists pior to calling `incr`.

**In short**: What you did is fine. But don't expect to be the only one who calls an standard command.